# C++ returning pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int* createArray();

int main() {
    int *arr = createArray();
    cout << "Main: " << arr << endl;

    arr[0] = 0;
    arr[1] = 1;

    cout << arr[0] << endl;
    cout << arr[1] << endl;
}

int* createArray() {
    int arr[2];
    cout << "createArray()1: " << arr << endl;
    return arr;
}
```

I don't understand why if I only call this statement

```
cout << arr[0] << endl;
```

or

```
cout << arr[1] << endl;
```

can show a correct value. 
But if I call both statement, it will show

```
createArray()1: 00AFFAF4
Main: 00AFFAF4
0
11533068  //Don't show 1
```

Comment: [Compile with warnings.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2084c17e9d9ca5fd)

Comment: [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope/6445794#6445794)

Comment: You can not return a pointer to an object allocated on the stack, since it will be destroyed as soon as you exit. Use [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/).

Comment: @xzoert no. Don't use malloc in C++.

Comment: ops, it's c+++, right. sorry!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pointer returned by `createArray` points to a non-existing object. The local array was destroyed when the function returned. When you dereference the dangling pointer in `main`, the behaviour of your program is undefined.

Solution: Don't ever return pointers or references to local variables. In this case, you could for example return a copy of the array. You cannot return a raw array by value, but you can return a wrapper structure like `std::array<int, 2>`.

Comment: I don't understand why only call 
cout << arr[0] << endl; 
OR
cout << arr[1] << endl; is still working

Comment: @SinLok What do you mean by "still working"? The behaviour is undefined.

Comment: If I only call cout << arr[0] << endl; it will show 0. If I only call cout << arr[1] << endl; it will show 1. But if I call both statement, it will display 0 and 11533068 in visual studio

Comment: @SinLok in both cases the behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a pointer to local variable which is destroyed at function block end.

But beware, when you use new operator, you need to use delete somewhere else (atleast without of use of smart pointers).

Solution:

```
int* createArray() {
    int* arr = new int[2];
    // your code
    return arr;
}
```